# Command '['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD^1']' returned non-zero exit status 128

Tags: python, git, github-actions

I am a **beginner** in embedded programming and trying to set up a workflow where the code sizes are automatically put in database and compared with the previous revision. Beginner on Github as well obviously.
I am trying to have a python script called by a Github Action.

So here is the action:

```
- name: Stamp revision
        working-directory: cobrax
        continue-on-error: True
        run: |
          pip install psycopg2-binary
          pip install click
          pip install prettytable
          python3 codesizes.py stamp build/zephyr/zephyr.elf
```

And here is the problematic line in the python code, where I am trying to fetch the parent revision:

```
    revision = subprocess.check_output(
        ["git", "rev-parse", "{}".format(revision)], encoding="UTF-8"
    ).strip()
    parent_revision = subprocess.check_output(
        ["git", "rev-parse", "{}^1".format(revision)], encoding="UTF-8"
    ).strip()
```

Now, for revision that works perfectly. But, just because of the '^1' for parent revision, I keep getting the following error message from the github action:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '...' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

So, I tried a few things, notably:

```
["git", "rev-parse", "{}^".format(revision)], encoding="UTF-8"
    ).strip()
```

```
["git", "rev-list", "--parents", "-n", "1", revision, "|", "cut", "-d'", "'", "-f2-"], encoding="UTF-8"
```

But, the error comes from elsewhere. As I am a beginner, I wish someone would explain it to me because that obviously comes the virtual environment thing for github actions because on my ubuntu VM in the repo I don't have that problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, it turns out that the actions/checkout@v2 that I use defaults to a shallow --depth=1 clone. This allows me to use HEAD but **NOT** HEAD^

With my workflow configured as such:

```
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
```

Everything works !

Comment: There's a new syntax: `- checkout: self \n fetchDepth: 2`